# Why would form not submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've tried everything in my power to fix this but no way.
Searched all of the internet and read all sorts of "form not submitting" questions.

I've checked that all `input` tags are closed.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$connection = mysql_pconnect("localhost","test","test");
if(!$connection)
    header("Location: pages-error-500.php");
mysql_select_db("test");
session_start();

$username = '';
$password ='';
$gender = '';
$age = '';
$description = '';
$phone_number = '';
$mobile_money_number = '';
$GLOBALS['exist'] = "false";

if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['username']))
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    if(isset($_POST['password']))
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    if(isset($_POST['gender']))
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    if(isset($_POST['age']))
        $age = $_POST['age'];
    if(isset($_POST['phone_number']))
        $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
    if(isset($_POST['mobile_money_number']))
        $mobile_money_number = $_POST['mobile_money_number'];
    if(isset($_POST['description']))
        $description = $_POST['description'];

    $a = mysql_query('select count(*) from users where username = "'.$username.'"');
    if($a)
        $b = mysql_result($a,0);
    else 
        header("Location: pages-error-500.html");

    if($b != 0) //username exists
        $GLOBALS['exist'] = "true";
    else
    {
        $hash = hash('sha512',$password); 
        $a = mysql_query('insert into users values (null,"'.$username.'","'.$hash.'","'.$description.'","'.$gender.'",'.$age.',"./assets/images/users/profile_default","'.$phone_number.'","'.$mobile_money_number.'"');
        if(!$a)
            header("Location: pages-error-500.html");
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>        
    <!-- META SECTION -->
    <title>Quick Money Transfer - Signup</title>            
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- END META SECTION -->

    <!-- CSS INCLUDE -->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme" href="css/theme-default.css"/>
    <!-- EOF CSS INCLUDE -->                  
</head>
<body>
    <!-- START PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <div class="page-container">

        <!-- START PAGE SIDEBAR -->
        <div class="page-sidebar">
            <!-- START X-NAVIGATION -->
            <ul class="x-navigation">
                <li class="xn-logo">
                    <a href="../index.php">Quick Money Transfer</a>
                </li>


        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE SIDEBAR -->

        <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
        <div class="page-content">



            <!-- START BREADCRUMB -->
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages-login.php">Sing In</a></li>
                <li class="active">Create Account</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- END BREADCRUMB -->

            <!-- PAGE TITLE -->
            <div class="page-title">                    
                <h2><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></span>Sign Up</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->                

            <!-- PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
            <div class="page-content-wrap">                

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <!-- START VALIDATIONENGINE PLUGIN -->
                        <div class="block">                              
                            <form id="validate" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">                            
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?php
                                        if($GLOBALS['exist'] == "true")
                                            echo '<p><style="color: red;"><strong>Username exists already</strong></style></p>';
                                    ?>
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="validate[required,maxSize[20]] form-control" name="username"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, max size = 20</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" class="validate[required,minSize[8],maxSize[10]] form-control" id="password" name="password"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, min size = 8, max size = 10</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" class="validate[required,equals[password]] form-control"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, equals Password</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Age:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9    ">
                                        <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[integer],min[18],max[120]] form-control" name="age"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, integer, min value = 18, max = 120</span>
                                    </div>                        
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Gender:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <select class="validate[required] select" id="formGender" name="gender">
                                            <option value="">Choose option</option>
                                            <option value="1">Male</option>
                                            <option value="0">Female</option>
                                        </select>                           
                                        <span class="help-block">Required</span>
                                    </div>                        
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Tag</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="validate[false,maxSize[20]] form-control" placeholder="Just a user" name="description"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">A sentence defining you</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Phone number:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[integer],min[650000000],max[679999999]] form-control" name="phone_number"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, phone number</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>             
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">MTN mobile money number:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[integer],min[650000000],max[679999999]] form-control" name="mobile_money_number"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">Required, mobile money number</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>          
                                <div class="form-group">                        
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="validate[required]" name="terms" value="1"/> Yes, I accept your terms and conditions.
                                            </label>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit_button" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
                                </div>                                                                
                            </form>
                        </div>                                               
                        <!-- END VALIDATIONENGINE PLUGIN -->

                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->                
        </div>            
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER -->

    <!-- START PRELOADS -->
    <audio id="audio-alert" src="audio/alert.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="audio-fail" src="audio/fail.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <!-- END PRELOADS -->                 

<!-- START SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- START PLUGINS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- END PLUGINS -->

    <!-- THIS PAGE PLUGINS -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/icheck/icheck.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/mcustomscrollbar/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js'></script>        
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js'></script>        

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/validationengine/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/validationengine/jquery.validationEngine.js'></script>        

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js'></script>                

    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/plugins/maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput.min.js'></script>
    <!-- END THIS PAGE PLUGINS -->               

    <!-- START TEMPLATE -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/settings.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/actions.js"></script>
    <!-- END TEMPLATE -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jvalidate = $("#validate").validate({
            ignore: [],
            rules: {                                            
                    login: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            maxlength: 20
                    },
                    password: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 8,
                            maxlength: 10
                    },
                    're-password': {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 8,
                            maxlength: 10,
                            equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    age: {
                            required: true,
                            min: 15,
                            max: 100
                    },
                    email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                    },
                    date: {
                            required: true,
                            date: true
                    },

                }                                        
            });                               

    </script>

<!-- END SCRIPTS -->          

</body>
```

I'm new to web. I've tried `<button>..</buton>`,`<button>`,`<button />` and even `<input />` but none submits the form.

Comment: Are you sure the `form` action is set properly?

Comment: What happens when you remove the action attribute? Any error in the console?

Comment: Removing the action parameter does not change anything.

Comment: Check the browser console for any errors.

Comment: @angelcool.net Clean! no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I thought single quotes and double quotes could be used interchangeably for strings.
I fixed this by using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` instead of the single quotes version.